# How can I stop my rigid body scene with intersecting objects from exploding?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I tried to look for an answer, but didnt find one.

Here's the situation:

- I have a building consisting of many hundred objects.
- It is "floating" and the mesh(es) are not connected, so its completely unstable. Meshes will fall directly down due to gravity.
- As the building is made very roughly, meshes are sometimes overlapping, or intersect pretty often. Due to this, the meshes "explode" directly after frame 1.

I want to fire cannon-balls at this building to show destruction stages.

Is it possible to ignore the collision of themselves (so the meshes will just be effected by he cannonball, not themselves), and make them "float" from the beginning? I played around with "start deactivated", but it didn't work.

Comment: when you activate the physic simulation, if you have anything overlapped, pieces will explode. I fear you need to fix the position of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can animate the "dynamic" attribute of an active rigid body to control during your timeline when an object become "physically active".

Objects will explode if they overlap.

Check these settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thx a lot for your answer, Sanbaldo.
Your answer was very helpful. I found a workaround for my needs. The key factor for not working with rigid body 100% is, that all meshes overlap. :D So: no chance.

thx anyway!
Cheers